# D3 "mousemove" slow down

Tags: angular, d3.js

I have an Angular App and using D3 with a SVG.

Inside there is a "mousemove" event.
The app is complex meanwhile but everything worked fine.

Now the D3 "mousemove" Event slows down the whole app even with out any logic. All made changes had nothing to do with it an where pretty simple.

```
d3
 .select(this.svg.nativeElement)
 .on('mousemove', function() {});
```

This is enough to slow it down.

The Chrome Profiler shows me a lot & long "mousemove" executions. But the most of the time it should be idle.

Expected (older version):
[image: Expected profile]

Current:
[image: Current profile]

I cant find the reason for this and could use any hint where to search this issue?

Comment: I think it is because change detection is triggering on every mouse move. You should run the code outside of the zone. Insert `NgZone` in your constructor and run all the code inside `ngZone.runOutsideAngularZone`

Comment: Interessting, never tried it before. Thanks, I ll try it out.

Answer (score 2):

The effect is interessting that the performance is very good on closing the Developer-Console.

Anyway the solution was to put it outside the Angular Zone (thanks @alt255).

like this:

```
constructor(private ngZone:NgZone) {}

...

 this.ngZone.runOutsideAngular(() => {

 d3
 .select(this.svg.nativeElement)
 .on('mousemove', function() {});   

 });
```